# Matlab: Error with arguments using ode solver

Tags: matlab, syntax-error, ode

There is no specific error, it just simply says "error" and shows a line in ode45 that supposedly is not in line with what I have written. If someone could give me a quickfix to this problem I would be greatful. Code and error message presented below:

Code:

```
tstart = 0;
tfinal = 10;
y0 = [0.18; 0.10; 0; 0];
[t,y] = ode45(@secondODE,[tstart tfinal], y0);

function dy = secondODE(t,y)
dy = zeros(4,1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -c/A2*y(1);
dy(3) = y(4);
dy(4) = D2/B2 + c*C2/(A2*B2)*y(1);
end
```

Error message:

```
Error in ode45 (line 115)
odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);

Error in bJAa (line 4)
[t,y] = ode45(@secondODE,[tstart tfinal], y0);
```

Comment: In your function `secondODE`, the variables `c`, `A2`, `B2`, `C2` and `D2` are not defined.

Comment: Try executing `dbstop if error`, then run your code and see where it stops.

Comment: In the examples for the same error message "Error in ode45 (line 115)" that google finds, it is always some prior problem with the definition of the parameters. So to repeat @Bebs, post a minimal **working** example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Replacing every unknown value by one, just to try, made it work with no errors. No repro.

Comment: Do I have to define the constants inside the function? These are not global? I think I see the error then, thanks! I remember now that all constants have to be passed to the function in Matlab.